# Comparing dates in 2 different formats to match or not with Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to compare date that comes from **ActionMailbox** `mail.date` with a **date field in my PostgreSQL DB Table** to check if a post for the same date already exists. The dates comes in different format I guess, how canI format them in same way to compare? The time section is irrelevant.

---

Date format that comes from email as below I guess. Looking at the Logs on server

Date: Wed, 24 Mar 2021 09:57:57 +0000
[image]

---

Date format I have in the DB is as below. Output of `Post.last in rails c`

date: "2021-03-24 09:57:57.000000000 +0000
[image]

---

**I need to check if dates matches or not?**

Btw the interesting thing is, I can just save `mail.date` to db without any particular formatting, I guess it is formatting itself before saving.

Comment: You can use [`Time.zone.parse`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse) to convert the string into a time

Comment: What database type is `posts.date`?

Answer (score 0):

> Date format I have in the DB is as below.

Databases don't store timestamps nor dates as strings, [they're stored as numbers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). The string format is just for humans. Unless you're storing the date as a string.

> I'm trying to compare date that comes from ActionMailbox mail.date with a date field in my PostgreSQL DB Table to check if a post for the same date already exists.

Those are standard date formats, [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#appendix-A) and [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). ***So long as your date column has a date type*** you don't need to convert them. Rails or Postgres will take care of the conversion.

```
Thing.where(date: mail.date)
```

However, your "date" field is storing a timestamp. It might be misnamed, or it might be mistyped. If you only want to store the date, use `t.date` in your migration.

---

If you did, you'd [parse](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse) them into Time objects, then compare.

```
t1 = Time.zone.parse("Wed, 24 Mar 2021 09:57:57 +0000")
t2 = Time.zone.parse("2021-03-24 09:57:57.000000000 +0000")
p t1 == t2
```

> Btw the interesting thing is, I can just save mail.date to db without any particular formatting, I guess it is formatting itself before saving.

Rails type conversion is parsing the String into an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object.

```
> thing = Thing.new
> thing.created_at = "Wed, 24 Mar 2021 09:57:57 +0000"
> thing.created_at
=> Wed, 24 Mar 2021 04:57:57.000000000 CDT -05:00
> thing.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```